# Bluetooth application

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am making bluetooth application in which I want to send data using bluetooth. That  task I am able to do. But after that I want open any particular file from device. Then How can I do it? I have written the code below.

```
package com.example.blue;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {




    private static final int DISCOVER_DURATION=300;
    private static final int REQUEST_BLU=1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String path="/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20141018_152852.jpg";

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        File file = new File(path);

        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        String ext=file.getName().substring(file.getName().indexOf(".")+1);
        String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);

        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),type);

        startActivity(intent);

    }

    public void sendViaBluetooth(View v){
        BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        if (btAdapter == null) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Bluetooth not supported" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else
        {
            enableBluetooth();
        }
    }

    public void enableBluetooth(){
        Intent discoveryIntent= new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoveryIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, DISCOVER_DURATION);
        startActivityForResult(discoveryIntent, REQUEST_BLU);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if(resultCode == DISCOVER_DURATION && requestCode == REQUEST_BLU)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"md5sum.txt");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(f));

            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            List<ResolveInfo> appsList = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

            if(appsList.size()>0)
            {
                String packageName = null;
                String className = null;
                boolean found = false;

                for(ResolveInfo info : appsList)
                {
                        packageName = info.activityInfo.packageName;
                        if(packageName.equals("com.android.bluetooth"))
                        {
                            className = info.activityInfo.name;
                            found = true;
                            break;
                        }
                }

                if(!found){
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Bluetooth haven't been found" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else
                {
                    intent.setClassName(packageName, className);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"Bluetooth is cancelled" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whenever I luanch this application main screen is displayed then it stops working.

Comment: Please post Logcat output

Comment: You may not have permissions to explicitly launch a system application activity which in this case is Bluetooth. Please post logcat details for solution